# SP2013 : Large number of alerts

Tags: 2013

I have 100,000 users and they suscribe for the alerts . I created a webpart , and created code where a user can suscribe for alerts and it sets the alert on the document library .

My requirement is i need to pull alerts and display top 5 suscribed alerts for a list item for particular user by creation date. What is efficent code example where i can pull alerts easily without much delay ? (Assume all 100,000 users have suscribed for alerts ) 
Is rest api , CSOM or server side best ? I am not sure if we have apis for alerts.

Comment: For that amount of data I recommend you use server side coding with LINQ. With CAML and CSOM you can have problems with the threshold

Comment: but internally linq is converted to caml i believe

Comment: What do you mean when you say you need to pull the top 5 alerts?

Comment: Documentation for doing this client side is woefully less. SSOM would be the way to go. https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spalert.aspx

Comment: @DanielZiga, I'm guessing top 5 sorted by created date.

Comment: Top 5 of what? You need to be more specific

Comment: I'm not talking about LINQ to Sharepoint. I use LINQ to Object.
I have perform querys over 300.000 registers and filter them with LINQ to object, with no problem of performance

Comment: Top 5 alerts based on user since that is what op's mentioned in his question.